# Ruby is trying to use SQLite while I set up MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

*Yes, this question has been asked before. 2 years ago. I felt bad about bumping it up, and figured it'd be a better idea to start a new thread.*

Much like the other question's OP, I have generated my Rails app correctly, changed my databases.yml to use MySQL, and still it is trying to use SQLite3. When I run a rake db: command, it works without errors. It generates the tables in the database, but in the browser, the applications keeps giving errors suggesting it is trying to access (/create) a sqlite database.

Has anyone yet found an answer to this issue? My databases.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  database: robinkanters_dev
  username: [[ correct username ]]
  password: [[ correct password ]]

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  database: robinkanters_test
  username: [[ correct username ]]
  password: [[ correct password ]]


production:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  database: robinkanters_prod
  username: [[ correct username ]]
  password: [[ correct password ]]
```

Robin Kanters

*PS. This is my first time posting on SO, please go easy on me*

EDIT: I figured I didn't really explain the problem.

Comment: Did you restart your server after making the changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should restart the server, and if you are running it on production mode, try

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

HTH

Comment: ...And it was as simple as restarting the server. I feel so stupid now, but thank a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

check your gemfile if rails version is 3.x.
remove sqlite3 gem and add mysql gem.
restart server